# Figuring out labeling for classes when using sklearn MLP.predict_proba() function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, classification

I am creating a Neural Net with labeled classes that are a list of binary values and there are 1167 classes. I want to utilize the MLP.predict_proba() to output the top 5 classes based on prediction probabilities but the output is a np array with probabilities for each class labeled just by index values i.e.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij5du.png)

[image]

I want to figure out what classes are linked to these probabilities and the predict function correctly outputs the binary list that represents the class that it was predicted to. Is there anyway for me to manually label the classes to these unique binary lists? I basically have labeled classes and my neural net is able to output the correct binary list for its predictions just when I use predict_proba() it gives me just probabilities with no clear indication of what classes these probabilities are for. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: add your code and then we will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `classes_` of the mlp after fitting. As per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier):

> classes_ : array or list of array of shape (n_classes,) Class labels
>   for each output.

It will print out the classes learnt from the dataset (mostly in alphabetical order).

The `predict_proba()` will be outputing the values in the same order.

Comment: It still outputs 0-1164 as the class not the binary list that represents that class. Is there some way for me to manually label the classes?

Comment: @deadKoyla How was the classes sent to `fit()`. Did you converted the classes to 0-1164 before training?